# Are sales values decreasing over time? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe full of stock transactions. I want to calculate how I can tell if a certain account is ordering less than they usually do.

NB: some cusotmers might place a big order (double the size of normal orders) and then take twice as long to order again. Or half the size and order double the frequency as normal.

Data layout:

SA_DACCNT = Account number
SA_TRREF = Invoice No

```
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| SA_DACCNT | SA_TRDATE  | SA_TRREF | SA_TRVALUE | SA_PRODUCT |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| GO63      | 01/05/2019 | 11587    | 0.98       | R613S/6    |
| GO63      | 01/05/2019 | 11587    | 0.98       | R614S/6    |
| AAA1      | 01/05/2019 | 11587    | 1.96       | R613S/18   |
| GO63      | 01/05/2019 | 11587    | 2.5        | POST3      |
| DOD2      | 01/07/2019 | 11588    | 7.84       | R613S/18   |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
```

So Far:

I've tried to group by customer and resample the columns into quarters and analyse the z score of the last quarter for each customer, but it doesn't always work out correctly as not everyone orders quarterly. So there are gaps which skew the figures.

I've also tired using fitting a linear model to the figures for each customer and using the coefficient as a metric to determine if spend is down. But it still doesn't look right.

I've been looking at is_monotonic_increasing and other such functions but still unable to find what I'm looking for, i'm sure there is a statistical technique for it but it aludes me.

I'm pretty new to all this and am left scratching my head on hows best to tackle it.

My goal is to determine WHO has spent less (over their last few orders) than they usually do.

Bascially who do we need to call / chase / send offers etc.

Any ideas on the correct way to analyse this would be appreaciated. Not looking to copy someones code, I'm sure i can work that bit out myself.

EDIT:

I've also now tried using diff to calcualte the average distace between orders and resampling to this value, then calculating the Z score. But still its not what I expect.